# How to display user items from get function?

Tags: angular, user-profile

I am trying to create  a profile page in angular, but for some reason the code is not working as expected.

I have been trying to do some research on the internet on how maybe documentation has been changed or whether there are different ways to do so, but unfortunately without success.

in vscode it tells me that function.user does not exist, but this makes sense (right?) since it has to be obtained by the get function. But whenever I try to compile it throws me an error.

profile.component.html:

```
<h1>Profile page</h1>

<div *ngIf="user">
  <h2 class="page-header">{{ user.name }}</h2>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Username: {{ user.username }}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Email: {{ user.email }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

profile.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-profile",
  templateUrl: "./profile.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./profile.component.css"]
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Object;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(
      profile => {
        this.user = profile.user;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts getProfile():

```
  getProfile() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: this.authToken
    });
    this.loadToken();
    // headers.append("authorization", this.authToken);
    // headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return this.http
      .get("http://localhost:3000/users/profile", {
        headers: headers
      })
      .pipe(map(res => res));
  }
```

Running the get request in postman returns me:

```
{
    "user": {
        "_id": "2dc35454fe34239e6",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "john@doe.com",
        "username": "John",
        "password": "andahashedpasswordinhere",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

with the

```
this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
this.user = profile.user;
      }
```

function I am hoping to obtain said object and insert it in this.user so that the HTML components can fetch the info and insert it.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error function.user is not defined?

Comment: Im running Angular using ng serve and when it shows in the terminal after adding the line this.user = profile.user;.  The full error: "ERROR in src/app/components/profile/profile.component.ts(23,29): error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Object'."

Comment: Hi Shandorius, welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [_Minimal, Reproducible Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue that you're facing.

Comment: @Shandorius, You should initialize the `user`  after declaring it. `user = {};` Variables of type Object only allow you to assign any value to them. You can’t call arbitrary methods on them, even ones that actually exist. You should Probably do something like `user = new User();` in your component